Interchange Start Date, End Date and other Columns with Earlier Row if Dates greater than 8 in pandas dataframe
Data:
# Sample data
data = {
    'Start Date': ['2022-10-18', '2022-10-25', '2023-04-17'],
    'End Date': ['2022-10-20', '2023-04-06', '2023-07-04'],
    'Close1': [17486.95, 17656.35, 17706.85],
    'Close2': [17563.95, 17599.15, 19389.00],
    'NF_BEES1': [0.58, 0.19, 0.12],
    'NF_BEES2': [0.63, 0.75, 0.73],
    'Difference': [77.00, -57.20, 1682.15],
    'Days Difference': [2, 163, 78]
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

# Convert date columns to datetime
df['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])
df['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'])

Output:
    Start Date  End Date    Close1  Close2  NF_BEES1    NF_BEES2    Difference  Days Difference
0   2022-10-18  2022-10-20  17486.95    17563.95    0.58    0.63    77.00   2
1   2022-10-25  2023-04-06  17656.35    17599.15    0.19    0.75    -57.20  163
2   2023-04-17  2023-07-04  17706.85    19389.00    0.12    0.73    1682.15 78

If Days Difference column > 8 , then create new row in df & End Date of Earlier row should be Start Date in new row & Start Date of current row (Days Difference >8) should be End Date.
Close1, Close2, NF_BEES1 , NF_BEES2 values should also be changed like Start Date & End Date. Based on that Days Difference needs to be calculated for new row
My Code (Not working as Expected):
# Iterate through the DataFrame
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    rows.append(row)
    if row['Days Difference'] > 8:
        # Create a new row
        new_row = row.copy()
        new_row['Start Date'] = rows[-2]['End Date']
        new_row['Close1'] = rows[-2]['Close2']
        new_row['NF_BEES1'] = rows[-2]['NF_BEES2']
        new_row['End Date'] = row['Start Date']
        new_row['Close2'] = row['Close1']
        new_row['NF_BEES2'] = row['NF_BEES1']
        new_row['Difference'] = (new_row['Close2'] - new_row['Close1'])
        new_row['Days Difference'] = (new_row['End Date'] - new_row['Start Date']).days
        print(new_row)
        print(type(new_row))

# Create a new DataFrame with the split rows
new_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
new_df

My Output:

Start Date  End Date    Close1  Close2  NF_BEES1    NF_BEES2    Difference  Days Difference
0   2022-10-18  2022-10-20  17486.95    17563.95    0.58    0.63    77.00   2
1   2022-10-25  2023-04-06  17656.35    17599.15    0.19    0.75    -57.20  163
2   2023-04-17  2023-07-04  17706.85    19389.00    0.12    0.73    1682.15 78

Expected Output:
Start Date  End Date    Close1  Close2  NF_BEES1    NF_BEES2    Difference  Days Difference
18  2022-10-18  2022-10-20  17486.95    17563.95    0.58    0.63    77.00   2
19  2022-10-20  2022-10-25  17563.95    17656.35    0.63    0.19    93  5
20  2023-04-06  2023-04-17  17599.15    17706.85    0.75    0.12    107 11


You didn't mention the fate of Close/NF_BEES/Difference in your question. While this can be inferred from the output better [edit] the question to be explicit ;)

Added details in query, Thanks @mozway , @e-motta!!

Assuming your columns are sorted in the specific order 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'Close1', 'Close2', 'NF_BEES1', 'NF_BEES2', you can use shift conditionally like so:
out = df.copy()

mask = df["End Date"] - df["Start Date"] > pd.Timedelta(days=8)

out.loc[mask, ["Start Date", "Close1", "NF_BEES1"]] = df.shift().shift(-1, axis=1)
out.loc[mask, ["End Date", "Close2", "NF_BEES2"]] = df.shift(axis=1)

out["Difference"] = out["Close2"] - out["Close1"]
out["Days Difference"] = (out["End Date"] - out["Start Date"]).dt.days

  Start Date   End Date    Close1    Close2  NF_BEES1  NF_BEES2  Difference  Days Difference
0 2022-10-18 2022-10-20  17486.95  17563.95      0.58      0.63        77.0                2
1 2022-10-20 2022-10-25  17563.95  17656.35      0.63      0.19        92.4                5
2 2023-04-06 2023-04-17  17599.15  17706.85      0.75      0.12       107.7               11


seems a bit complex with many shift, no? ;)

@mozway Arguably, yes, but I couldn't come up with anything simpler. :-)

It's a nice way to keep it short, but you should just mention that this requires the columns to be sorted in the specific A1/A2/B1/B2/C1/C2 order, otherwise this will mixup the values.

@mozway Good point, I added a comment about this.

IIUC, use a mask, a copy of End and shift:
# identify rows to change
m = df['Days Difference'].gt(8)

# keep a copy of the previous End
prev_end = df['End Date'].shift()

# update the rows
df.loc[m, 'End Date'] = df['Start Date']
df.loc[m, 'Start Date'] = prev_end

Output:
  Start Date   End Date    Close1    Close2  NF_BEES1  NF_BEES2  Difference  Days Difference
0 2022-10-18 2022-10-20  17486.95  17563.95      0.58      0.63       77.00                2
1 2022-10-20 2022-10-25  17656.35  17599.15      0.19      0.75      -57.20              163
2 2023-04-06 2023-04-17  17706.85  19389.00      0.12      0.73     1682.15               78

generalization
If you want a new DataFrame as output, just do the same on a copy, and if you want to update multiple columns apply the shift to all at once, and update the differences then perform a subtraction (and convert to days when needed):
# make a copy
new_df = df.copy()

# shift the columns
m = df['Days Difference'].gt(8)
new_df.loc[m, ['End Date', 'Close2', 'NF_BEES2']] = df[['Start Date', 'Close1', 'NF_BEES1']][m].values
new_df.loc[m, ['Start Date', 'Close1', 'NF_BEES1']] = df[['End Date', 'Close2', 'NF_BEES2']].shift()[m].values

# update the differences
new_df['Difference'] = new_df['Close2'].sub(new_df['Close1'])
new_df['Days Difference'] = new_df['End Date'].sub(new_df['Start Date']).dt.days

Output:
  Start Date   End Date    Close1    Close2  NF_BEES1  NF_BEES2  Difference  Days Difference
0 2022-10-18 2022-10-20  17486.95  17563.95      0.58      0.63        77.0                2
1 2022-10-20 2022-10-25  17563.95  17656.35      0.63      0.19        92.4                5
2 2023-04-06 2023-04-17  17599.15  17706.85      0.75      0.12       107.7               11


IIUC, you'd also need to change columns 'Close...' and 'NF_BEES...'.

@e-motta, sure it's the same logic, although this was not explained in the question.

True, I inferred that from the title and expected output, but the question itself doesn't mention it.

@e-motta I added the full logic, I'll ask OP to explicit this
